# How do I get the explanation of gcc -s?

Tags: gcc

I got the meaning of "gcc -s" through the search engine. It means stripping the symbols when linking.

But how can I get this information using "man gcc" or "gcc --help"? It seems to have no relevant information:

```
root@desktop:~# gcc --help
Usage: gcc [options] file...
Options:
  -pass-exit-codes         Exit with highest error code from a phase
  --help                   Display this information
  --target-help            Display target specific command line options
  --help={target|optimizers|warnings|params|[^]{joined|separate|undocumented}}[,...]
                           Display specific types of command line options
  (Use '-v --help' to display command line options of sub-processes)
  --version                Display compiler version information
  -dumpspecs               Display all of the built in spec strings
  -dumpversion             Display the version of the compiler
  -dumpmachine             Display the compiler's target processor
  -print-search-dirs       Display the directories in the compiler's search path
  -print-libgcc-file-name  Display the name of the compiler's companion library
  -print-file-name=<lib>   Display the full path to library <lib>
  -print-prog-name=<prog>  Display the full path to compiler component <prog>
  -print-multi-directory   Display the root directory for versions of libgcc
  -print-multi-lib         Display the mapping between command line options and
                           multiple library search directories
  -print-multi-os-directory Display the relative path to OS libraries
  -print-sysroot           Display the target libraries directory
  -print-sysroot-headers-suffix Display the sysroot suffix used to find headers
  -Wa,<options>            Pass comma-separated <options> on to the assembler
  -Wp,<options>            Pass comma-separated <options> on to the preprocessor
  -Wl,<options>            Pass comma-separated <options> on to the linker
  -Xassembler <arg>        Pass <arg> on to the assembler
  -Xpreprocessor <arg>     Pass <arg> on to the preprocessor
  -Xlinker <arg>           Pass <arg> on to the linker
  -combine                 Pass multiple source files to compiler at once
  -save-temps              Do not delete intermediate files
  -pipe                    Use pipes rather than intermediate files
  -time                    Time the execution of each subprocess
  -specs=<file>            Override built-in specs with the contents of <file>
  -std=<standard>          Assume that the input sources are for <standard>
  --sysroot=<directory>    Use <directory> as the root directory for headers
                           and libraries
  -B <directory>           Add <directory> to the compiler's search paths
  -b <machine>             Run gcc for target <machine>, if installed
  -V <version>             Run gcc version number <version>, if installed
  -v                       Display the programs invoked by the compiler
  -###                     Like -v but options quoted and commands not executed
  -E                       Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link
  -S                       Compile only; do not assemble or link
  -c                       Compile and assemble, but do not link
  -o <file>                Place the output into <file>
  -x <language>            Specify the language of the following input files
                           Permissible languages include: c c++ assembler none
                           'none' means revert to the default behavior of
                           guessing the language based on the file's extension
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `man gcc`:

```
   -s  Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the
       executable.
```

I found this by searching for "`-s`" (note leading and trailing space) in the man pager.

Comment: Why would you want to use this option? It doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: @bearbin: It reduce executable's size

Answer (score 3):

On `man gcc` only more used and useful options are listed. The rest of documentation can be found on [gcc online web page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/)

From: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options

> -s Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.